# Chart.js custom tooltip events

Tags: chart.js

I m working on charts using the chart.js library. I want to show image gallery like a carousel on click of any segment of pie/doughnut chart. I'm not able to find the proper solution. Please suggest some solution

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly what you are trying  is to trigger an event after user clicks on chart segment. chart.js has this prototype method `getElementAtEvent()`; See the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods).

It seems as a good place to start - you could create some function to open image gallery and call it there.

And the gallery/slider implementation is a separate issue, but if you are using some of the popular ui libraries some of them have a solution for that already. Bootstrap, for example has [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/),  and JQuery has many plugins for that purpose. Here are some [examples](https://dcrazed.com/free-responsive-jquery-image-sliders/). Hope this helps...